# Combining surface plot, explicit colour and legends in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This question is a result of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205510/specific-tikz-file-cannot-be-input-in-latex). I would like to make a surface plot using tikz/pgfplots using explicit colour and including legends. Is this possible? I have gone through the entire manual for pgfplots without seeing any examples of this combined. If I try to do it I get the error

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, color input!=colormap requires 'point meta=sym
```

but, I have set point meta to explicit symbolic and it works if I leave out the legend.

[Here](http://speedy.sh/ZvNgX/Sens-Hest-v0.tikz) is the specific tikz file, right below the data is the legend entry which is commented out for it to work.

I would very much appreciate any feedback on this, it would be beyond cool to get it to work, but on the other hand it would be nice to know if it is not possible so I can let it go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is configuration bug in `pgfplots`: the default legend for mesh/surface plots relies on a colormap -- but it does not set `mesh/color input=colormap`. Consequently, it inherits the choice of the plot and is confused.

A simple work-around is to add

```
legend image post style={/pgfplots/mesh/color input=colormap},
```

to your option list (or to configure this in your main tex file using `\pgfplotsset{...}`).

You can also add a different colormap to that list or choose an entirely different legend (like `area legend`).

I fixed the configuration issue for the next release of `pgfplots`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am by no means an expert so you may excuse stupidity. Doing this allows me to get legends, which is of course nice but it does not use colours that fit the ones from external (i.e. the explicit colours in the data). Is this also possible to get? :)

Comment: I have changed to just using your colormaps and it looks beautiful :)

Comment: I am glad that my answer addresses your needs. Regarding the actual colors: pgfplots cannot use explicit colors of the surface for the legend. Doing so would be a feature request (a very special one as well imho).

Comment: Yea! I realised that, it was indeed not very important to be able to do.